# Entity Framework mapping issue : map incorrect field

Tags: entity-framework

I tried to change the EF mapping, but it seems that EF still tries to find incorrect field

Below is the code for the CXL_ManagerView class

```
[NotMapped]
public string CustomerEmpID { get; set; }

[Column(name: "CustomerEmpID")]
public byte[] CustomerEmpID_Encrypted { get; set; }
```

Below is the code of the error line

```
var managerView = Database.SqlQuery<CXL_ManagerView>("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Legacy].CXL_ManagerView").ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

I am confident that the returned fields from the database include the 'CustomerEmpID' field, and it is of the byte type.

[Screenshot returned by the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05Y8N.png)

EF should be trying to find field ‘CustomerEmpID’, but it still returns an error message：

The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'CompPlanningWebFormAPI.EF.CXL_ManagerView'. A member of the type, 'CustomerEmpID_Encrypted', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

How to correctly configure mapping with Entity Framework (EF)

Comment: Exactly what version of EF are you using? Are you using _cached view configurations_ on-disk?

Comment: the EF version is 6.4.4，I used Database View

Comment: i had suspicion that ef 6 confuses between the `[NotMapped]` and `[Column(name: CustomerEmpID)]`. have you tried to normally map the `CustomerEmpID` and have `CustomerEmpID_Decrypted` instead of flipping the column mapping? that or `Database.SqlQuery<>` ignores any mapping attributes - i personally prefer to work with models than raw queries.

Comment: normally mapping the CustomerEmpID would work, but unfortunately due to some other factors, I cannot do so.